# Splint Out of Range Error

Tags: splint

I am using Splint 3.1.2, and I am getting Out of Range Error during Execution of Splint in My Code. My code has 2000 .C files, my execution is Stopping every time in some .c files, because of Out of Range Error. Can anyone Help me on this Issue ???.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Did you eventually solved your problem ? If not, an MCVE would help.